# webRTC : SimplePeer ignore the iceServer config

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to configure a visioconference system beetwen two person with webRTC. For this i'm using the SimplePeer package : https://github.com/feross/simple-peer

Everything work fine on my own network. I want now to connect using my stun server but no matter what address I enter for the stun server it doesn't change. The config of the iceServers seems to be ignored.

Here is my code :

```
navigator.getUserMedia({
    video: true,    
    audio: true     
}, function (stream) {
    let p = new SimplePeer({
        initiator: initiator,   
        stream: stream,         
        trickle: false,         
        config: { iceServers: [{ url: 'stun:---:1' }]} 
    })
    bindEvents(p)  
}, function (err) {
    console.log('error', err)
})
```

Can someone help me on that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC by default will add your local ip address, which is why your connection works on your local network.  That's a good place to start.  Most likely your stun server isn't configured properly.  You can test it out at this page.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/

The default stun server on that page is a free public server from google which you can use.

Also, it looks like your trying to connect to your stun server on port 1.  That's a reserved port.  Don't do that.

Also, I think I read recently that trickle ice should be used.

Comment: Just something to add : with SimplePeer its urls and not url ;)